# Как в opencart 2 узнать логин или id текущего админа?

Tags: php, opencart

Как в opencart 2 узнать логин или id текущего админа?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В контроллере: подключаете модель user

```
$this->load->model('user/user');
```

Получаете id текущего пользователя из сессии:

```
$suid = $this->session->data['user_id']
```

Дёргаете модель, записываете в переменную:

```
$user_info = $this->model_user_user->getUser($suid);

print_r($user_info);
```

Получаете массив настроек текущего пользователя. Если задача выводить в файл представления:

```
$data['user_info'] = $user_info;
```

Далее в .tpl:

```
<?=$user_info;?>
```

Comment: что-то не получается )

Comment: Извините, не указал параметр user_id во время вызова метода  getUser(). Исправил.

Comment: Вам не обязательно подключать модель и делать все эти манипуляции. Существует специальный класс user в файле system/library/user.php. Его методы можно вызвать в любом контроллере админки. Если он не работает, значит что-то в этом классе сломали или он почему-то не подключился (скорее всего тоже что-то сломали).

Comment: Если задача состоит в том чтобы получить Id админа то достаточно будет, получить данные из сесии $this->session->data['user_id']

Comment: @Kernel Panic - бесспорно, такой подход отрабатывает на фронте. Но на бэке такие штуки блокируются. Вариант с запросом через бд более универсален.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте `$this->user->getId()`

Id адміна также можно получить из сессии `$this->session->data['user_id']`

Comment: пробовал, и происходит что то странное. Сайт просто ломается

Comment: Какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: в том то и дело, ошибок нет, вид сайтапросто меняется , как будто отключаются стил

Comment: Попробуйте в таком случае `$this->session->data['user_id']`